# window.scrollBy only works in Firefox?

Tags: javascript

In my website I have this javascript code, adding a vertical offset when in the url a specific section of the page is specified (#):

if (!!window.location.hash)
    window.scrollBy(0,-60);

However this only works in Firefox... I'm pretty sure window.location.hash works in all browsers, that is, the symbol "sharp" is correctly detected in the url.

However, the -60 offset only works in Firefox... this is the url, could you give me some insight ?

http://patrickdiviacco.co.cc/#432

thanks

Comment: This works in Chrome for me. What other browsers did you test?

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke so, in Chrome and Safari the page scroll is not the same that in Firefox. You see the list item title is not visible ? In firefox the list item is perfectly aligned with the top banner. (Again, I'm talking about urls with "#"

Comment: @galambalazs any url with "#" and an existing div id shows the issue: http://patrickdiviacco.co.cc/#432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it in IE 7 and it works, also in FireFox and Chrome...

If this really don't work try using this:

```
function jumpScroll(amount) {
  document.body.scrollLeft += amount;
}

jumpScoll(100);
```

or value which you want...

Comment: unfortunately it's not cross browser

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the default behavior is applied in a different order. So your code runs first, then the browser aligns the window according to the `#hash`. Push it to the *event queue* to run it afterwards.

```
if (typeof window.location.hash == "string") {
    setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollBy(0, -60); }, 1);
}
```